# How to register media keys in python

Tags: python, key, mp3, media

I have a mp3 playing program but how do I make it listen for media keys in the background. And would the Fn media keys be different to other dedicated media keys?

Comment: By media keys, do you mean the pause/play buttons some computers have with the Fn keys?

Comment: @mcchucklezz Yeah the Fn keys and Ive seen some keyboards with dedicated ones like the corsair k70(although I don't know if they're just macros to press the keys).

Comment: It really depends on if the function keys require holding down Fn, but in Python I would use pygame and find the key codes.

Comment: @mcchucklezz Alright thanks.Do you have any links to using that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Listener


def on_press(key):
    if str(key) == '<179>':
        # play pause media key was pressed
    if str(key) == '<176>':
        # next key was pressed
    if str(key) == '<177>':
        # previous key was pressed


def on_release(key):
    pass
    
    
listener_thread = Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=None)
# This is a daemon=True thread, use .join() to prevent code from exiting  
listener_thread.start()
```

[pynput~=1.4.5](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/335)

[Don't use the latest version until this issue is fixed](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/335)

Comment: Better late than never eh?

Comment: The bug fixes were implemented years ago so the links can be removed.

Comment: Not sure I can, because I can't confirm whether media stop has been added yet.

Answer (score 0):

[Use this](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html), but make sure to check if the media keys require Fn to be pressed or not.

Comment: As far as im aware the media keys do require Fn to be pressed

Comment: @Hello then you want to detect if both keys are pressed

Comment: How would I go about using that then? Everything i've tried doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Medias keys doesn't seem to be documented on the Pygame docs.