# Register/Recognize Multimedia Input (e.g. Play/Pause Button) from Bluetooth devices with Python

Tags: python, windows, bluetooth, playback, headphones

I have WH-1000XM3 Bluetooth Headphones and I am trying to register, when I press the play/pause button on them. I am on Windows 10.

I come from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48028022/how-to-register-media-keys-in-python) question, but it sadly just asks for the Multimedia keys on the keyboard.
It's possible to register these key presses with the following code with the `pynput` library:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.media_play_pause:
        # Play/Pause Key

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

This works for the button "media_play_pause"-Button in `pynput.keyboard.Keys`, but sadly the input from my Bluetooth headphone isn't recognized as that button. In fact, it isn't recognized as any button, the `on_press` function (as well as an `on_release` function) is not triggered when the Play/Pause button of the headphones is pressed.

So I guess the `pynput` library doesn't help.

Do you know a way to recognize the play/pause of content when a button is pressed or even know how to "simulate" a program to accept inputs from Bluetooth Headphones (like my Browser or my music program is doing for example)?

The goal is to trigger a function that executes a hotkey with `pyautogui` or a similar library.

Comment: Do you want to directly trigger the pause of the Bluetooth headset?

Comment: How can you pause a bluetooth headset? I want to pause media on my Windows system with my bluetooth headphones.
I press the button on the phones -> Signal gets sent to the connected Computer -> Python recognizes a pause signal -> I can write a program based on that

Comment: I have XM3, but my Windows 10 does not have Bluetooth, I will try again later.